# Compare multiple date fields on a page through javascript

Tags: javascript, date, onclick

How to efficiently compare dynamic number of dates on a page from a given date?

Consider following code:

```
<div id="dateFields">
    <input type="date" id="date1"/>
    <input type="date" id="date2"/>
    <input type="date" id="date3"/>
    <input type="date" id="date4"/>
    <input type="date" id="date5"/>
</div>
<div id="masterDate">
    <input type="date" id="comparator"/>
</div>
<button onClick="compareDate()">Compare Now</button>
```

Consider the dates in div with `id="dateFields` are in random numbers. Say 5 for now. And the date in div with `id="comparator` is the date which we need to compare all the dates with.

Now, for example, if the comparator date is set to "March, 2015" and all the values in dateFields are set dynamically by the user (Say "Feb, 2002", "Dec, 2010", "Aug, 2016", "Jul, 2019" and "Nov, 2015"). What is the most efficient and generic code I should write in the function `compareDate()` so that the output brings all the dates which are greater than the comparator.

**Edit:**
Here is my javascript function. But, I don't feel that this is the efficient way. And even this is no good for dynamic number of values.

```
function compareDate() {
    var v1 = document.getElementById("date1").value;
    var v2 = document.getElementById("date2").value;
    var v3 = document.getElementById("date3").value;
    var v4 = document.getElementById("date4").value;
    var v5 = document.getElementById("date5").value;
    var v6 = document.getElementById("comparator").value;
    var v7 = [ v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 ];
    var result = "";

    for (i = 0; i < v7.length; i++) {
        console.log(solidify(v7[i]));

        if (solidify(v6) < solidify(v7[i])) {
            result += v7[i];
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}

function solidify(date) {
    var tempResult = '';

    for (i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
        if (date.charAt(i) == '-') {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            tempResult += date.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    return tempResult;
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Explanation of the requirement with example.

There need not be any text-box, it may be just a set of `<td>`, `<p>` or may be just a `<div>` containing number of dates, which may vary from minimum 2 dates to max 50 dates(Say).

I'm just looking for a logic and hence was trying with text-boxes.

For a real time example, consider a City Municipality Management System, which keeps track of monthly deaths that occur in that city. Now, a clerk wants to know the details of citizens who died after 15th of that month, how will he get the data?

Comment: We will not do your work for you. If you get stuck, please show us what you have done so far, and we will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You also are missing a lot of key information . . . what kind of comparison (before? after? equal?, all three?), compare each individually or as a group (i.e., stop comparing if one of the dates meets some requirement?), how to indicate/store the results of the comparison, etc.

Comment: One thing that I can tell you is that, since you are not including a "day" value in your dates, you will need to set a standard one, in order to create your `Date` objects.  I would suggest insertin a " 1" to your input values, changing them from the "Jan, 2014" format to a "Jan 1, 2014" format.  That is a valid parameter for the `Date` constructor and all months have the 1st as a day, so there would be no issues with validity.

Comment: Okay, let me edit and post the code which I tried working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what you are asking, but there are still some requirements that you need to nail down, in order to make it truly "generic" (see below the code):

**HTML**

```
<div id="dateFields">
    <input type="date" id="date1"/>
    <input type="date" id="date2"/>
    <input type="date" id="date3"/>
    <input type="date" id="date4"/>
    <input type="date" id="date5"/>
</div>

<div id="masterDate">
    <input type="date" id="comparator"/>
</div>

<div id="results">
    Results: <span id="resultDates"></span>
</div>

<button onClick="compareDate()">Compare Now</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    function compareDate() {
        var aDates = document.getElementById("dateFields").getElementsByTagName("input");
        var sCompareDate = document.getElementById("comparator").value;
        var dCompareDate = formatDate(sCompareDate);
        var result = "";

        for (i = 0; i < aDates.length; i++) {
            var sCurrDate = aDates[i].value;

            if (dCompareDate < formatDate(sCurrDate)) {
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    result += ", ";
                }

                result += sCurrDate;
            }
        }

        if (result === "") {
            result = "No dates less than " + sCompareDate;
        }

        document.getElementById("resultDates").innerHTML = result;
    }

    function formatDate(sDate) {
        var regMonthYear = /[a-z]{3}, \d{4}/i;

        if (regMonthYear.test(sDate)) {
            sDate = sDate.replace(",", " 1,");
        }

        return new Date(sDate);
    }
</script>
```

Things that need to be worked out still:

1. **You must compare `Date` objects, not strings.**

To do what you are trying to do, you must use JavaScript `Date` objects.  Even if you are using am `<input>` with a `type` attribute of "date", its value is still a string.  If you compare that, it would be like asking if "orange" is less than "house" . . . JavaScript will give you an answer, but it will be, in no way, related to what you are looking for.

The JavaScript `Date` object has built in comparison functionality that will do exactly what you are looking for.

2 **You need to come up with some sort of standard for your date inputs and make sure that you have code to enforce them.**

While the `Date` object is VERY flexible when it comes to what inputs it will accept when you are creating a new instance, it does have its limits.  You can look at these two links for more information on valid string formats for creating dates:

**the ISO date format** - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx#ISO

**other date parsing rules** - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx#OtherDateFormats

Once you figured out which one(s) make the most sense for your needs, you really should set a common format (or group of formats) that you want to work with, and enforce that formatting on your inputs with validation rules.  If you don't, you will have to add LOTS of logic to validate all of the different possibilities, so that you know that you are going to get a valid `Date` object when you try to create it.

3 **You need to come up with some sort of standard output for your results.**

Ideally, if you want to create a truly "generic" date comparison function to meet what you are asking for, you want it to focus solely on the comparison and nothing else.  Something like this:

```
function compareDate(aDateGroup, dComparisonDate)
    var aGreaterThanDates = [];

    for (i = 0; i < aDateGroup.length; i++) {
        if (dCompareDate < aDateGroup[i]) {
            aGreaterThanDates.push(aDateGroup[i]);
        }
    }

    return aGreaterThanDates;
}
```

. . . where `aDateGroup` is an array of `Date` objects and `dCompareDate` is a `Date` object as well.

The function would take in the dates, compare them, and pass back the ones that passed the test.  Then you could cycle through the returned array and process those dates however you needed to.

This would also allow you to pass in dates from any source (i.e., like a collection of the `<td>`, `<p>`, and `<div>` elements that you mentioned in your second update), as long as they were converted to proper `Date` objects first.

4. **Determine whether or not you need to be flexible in your comparison.**

The above "ideal code" could actually be made even "more ideal" by adding some flexibility in the comparison function, by adding a few parameters to indicate what kind of comparison to do:

```
function compareDate(aDateGroup, dComparisonDate, sCompareDirection, bIncludeComparisonDate)
    var aPassedDates = [];

    for (i = 0; i < aDateGroup.length; i++) {
        if (sCompareDirection === "before") {
            if (bIncludeComparisonDate) {
                if (dCompareDate >= aDateGroup[i]) {
                    aPassedDates.push(aDateGroup[i]);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (dCompareDate > aDateGroup[i]) {
                    aPassedDates.push(aDateGroup[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (sCompareDirection === "after") {
            if (bIncludeComparisonDate) {
                if (dCompareDate <= aDateGroup[i]) {
                    aPassedDates.push(aDateGroup[i]);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (dCompareDate < aDateGroup[i]) {
                    aPassedDates.push(aDateGroup[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            if (dCompareDate == aDateGroup[i]) {
                aPassedDates.push(aDateGroup[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return aPassedDates;
}
```

The `sCompareDirection` parameter would allow you to determine the direction of the comparison.  "before" would check for values less than the comparison date, "after" would check for values greater than the comparison date, and any other value (or no value) would check for the dates being equal.

The `bIncludeComparisonDate` parameter would allow you to include the comparison date as part of the match.  A value of `true` would turn the "greater than" comparison to "greater than or equal to" and the "less than" comparison to "less than or equal to".

### Conclusion

Date comparison is actually a fairly common process, but it is also one that requires a LOT of thinking through to make flexible and foolproof.  If you don't catch some of these things early, you are asking for a world of hurt down the line, when you try to reuse what you have built and in a situation that doesn't quite match what you originally set up.   :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareDate() {
  var dateFields = document.getElementById('dateFields').getElementsByTagName('input');
  var comparatorDate = new Date(document.getElementById('comparator').value);
  var rslt = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < dateFields.length; i++) {
    if (new Date(dateFields[i].value) > comparatorDate) rslt.push(dateFields[i].value);
  }
  return rslt;
}
```

This was tested in chrome

Comment: That won't work . . . the `.value` property will return a string value . . . you would be doing a string compare, instead of a Date compare, which I don't think would be what he is looking for.

Comment: I assumed the user inputs the date using the date picker or according to the right format, which works, at least in Chrome, since the input field type is "date", but please see the above fix

Comment: Well, the only problem there is that the data samples that he provided (e.g., "March, 2105") are invalid string inputs for the `Date` constructor, so it would result in an invalid `Date` object.  It needs a day value as well (e.g., "March 1, 2015") to be valid.

Comment: @Vibhor Dube did not mention what browser he's using. It works perfectly for Chrome

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd recommend mentioning any browser requirements/restrictions in your answer . . . it creates `Invalid Date` values in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it  in following way :

```
 <script>
            function compareDate() {
                var v1 = document.getElementById("date1").value;
                var v2 = document.getElementById("date2").value;
                var v3 = document.getElementById("date3").value;
                var v4 = document.getElementById("date4").value;
                var v5 = document.getElementById("date5").value;
                var v6 = document.getElementById("comparator").value;
                var v7 = [ v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 ];
                var finalResult = "";
                for (k = 0; k < v7.length; k++) {
                    if (solidify(v6) < solidify(v7[k])) {
                        finalResult += v7[k];
                        finalResult += " and ";

                    }

                }
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = finalResult;
            }
            function solidify(date) {
                var result = '';
                for (i = 0; i < date.length; i++) {
                    if (date.charAt(i) == '-') {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        result += date.charAt(i);

                    }

                }
                return result;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: This actually helped me a lot. But, I wonder, how to implement this for dynamic number of date fields.

Comment: @VibhorDube, first off,dynamic word is too generic here ,please specify your requirement . if you are trying to create a page in which you are dynamically appending new textboxes then in that situtation this code may not work but if the efficiency is not as expexted then i would welcome further suggestions .......